# Django can't find locally-installed Python modules

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm running a Django-based website that's hosted on a shared server (i.e. I have only a limited account, no admin privileges). The server's administrator installed the Django modules for Python 2.7, but now I want to add a 3rd-party Django library I found called django-bleach. So I installed it locally, using

```
pip install --user django-bleach
```

Then, following the instructions [in the django-bleach documentation](https://bitbucket.org/ionata/django-bleach), I added 'django-bleach' to my INSTALLED_APPS list in `settings.py`. However, when I touched `wsgi.py` to get Apache to reload my code, I got an ImportError in my Apache log. Usually this means that the module I'm trying to import isn't in the PYTHONPATH, so I put a `print sys.path` statement in `wsgi.py`. This is what happens:

```
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error] sys.path is: ['/extra/www/html/quotes/quotes_django', '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', 
'/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/users/ejt64/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/users/ejt64/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/users/ejt64/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error] mod_wsgi (pid=29372): Target WSGI script '/extra/www/html/quotes/quotes_django/quotes_django/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error] mod_wsgi (pid=29372): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/extra/www/html/quotes/quotes_django/quotes_django/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error]   File "/extra/www/html/quotes/quotes_django/quotes_django/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error]   File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error]     django.setup()
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error]   File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error]   File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error]   File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error]     module = import_module(entry)
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error]     __import__(name)
[Mon Nov 24 13:44:58 2014] [error] ImportError: No module named django_bleach
```

Note that the `/users/ejt64/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` directory, which appears three times in sys.path, is my user-local Python location where django-bleach is installed. I made this directory world-readable, in case the Apache process was running into a permissions problem accessing my directory. So how can I be getting an ImportError?

It must be something to do with WSGI/Django, though, because if I just run Python in my Django app directory, I can do this:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Dec  3 2013, 08:35:16) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django_bleach
>>>
```

But my Django application somehow can't find the django_bleach module, even though it's looking in the right location.

**Additional Info**: My `wsgi.py` is just the standard one generated by `django-admin startproject`, plus a print statement:

```
import os 
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "quotes_django.settings")

import sys
print >>sys.stderr, "sys.path is: " + str(sys.path)

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: What is you dont install it with `--user`?

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment means. I have to install django-bleach with `--user` because I don't have root/sudo privileges on this server.

Comment: What does your `wsgi` file look like?  You can map the Python version there.

Comment: My `wsgi.py` is the one generated by Django's `startproject` command. I'll include it in my question just in case, but I don't know what you mean by "map the python version."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally solved my problem. It turns out that although `/users/ejt64/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` was on the PYTHONPATH being searched by WSGI, I had forgotten to make one of the directories along that path world-*executable*, so the Apache user couldn't access it.

Although all the directories and files were world-*readable*, a user can't read a world-readable file unless it has execute permissions on all the directories that contain it, and it turns out my home directory (`/users/ejt64`) was world-readable but not world-executable. Once I made this directory world-executable, the `ImportError` went away.

It sure would be nice if I could make Apache/WSGI/Python print an error message when it tries to read a directory on the PYTHONPATH but can't access it due to permissions.

Answer (score -1):

```
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Is relative to the user running apache.  What user is running apache?  Typically apache runs as the default user 'nobody' or 'apache'.  Having a relative path to '~' will point to the home directory of the user running apache.

I'd recommend using a virtualenv or specifying the absolute path to your local pip packages.  Going into your site-packages directory and running `pwd` will let you know the absolute path.  You may need to alter the permissions of your pip packages and directories as well if the user running apache can't read/write/execute against them.

It works fine when you drop into the Python REPL because you are executing everything as your user and '~' points to your home directory.

If you have access to edit the apache config files on your server, I'd recommend taking a look at this Django documentation,
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-a-virtualenv
Event if you don't use a virtualenv you will still need to set this accordingly to the absolute path of your local site-packages directory.

```
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com:/path/to/your/venv/lib/python3.X/site-packages
```

Comment: You're totally right, but I was misleading in my question. The PYTHONPATH printed out by Apache actually includes the absolute path to my user's home directory, not a `~` path. I thought it would just confuse things to include my username in the example.